# SvelteKit - How to make SCSS variables/mixins globally available to all components?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, sveltekit

In Nuxt, I use the [Style Resources package](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module) to make SCSS available globally and I can access variables and mixins in any component. How to do the same in SvelteKit?

Answer (score 16):

You should make the stylesheet available to the whole application. Personally I am using [svelte-preprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess).

To do this, just set some parameters in the svelte configuration file (`svelte.config.js`), asking to import a certain file into each sub stylesheet of your components.

```js
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess({
        scss: {
            prependData: `@import './src/style/app.scss';`
        }
    })
    ...
};
```

Then inside `app.scss` you can import any other file, for example `_variables.scss` where you are going to put all the global variables that need to be shared.

Answer (score 6):

For my case I creed a folder with differents files with varibles (for exemple colors.sccs etc.) in folder src and I imported it to main css file app.scss like this on the top of file:

```
@use "./colors";
```

and I imported app.scss in __layout.svelte
after that I can use my variables ans maximes in each component like this where I write my style:

```
<style lang="scss">
   @use "./colors";
   
   .myClass {
      color: colors.$myColor
   } 

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution I came up with. I've detailed my full code, and how to import styles globally here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75555487/3359291