# How to use vitePreprocess with global SCSS mixins in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

In my [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) project I am using SCSS and in order to include some mixins that are used throughout the project, I switched from `vitePreprocess` to `svelte-preprocess` and prepended them with `scss.prependData`. Now my config looks like this:

```
const config = {
  preprocess: preprocess({
    scss: {
      prependData: `@import './src/styles/prepend.scss';`,
    },
  }),
  // ..
  // Other options not relevant to the question
}
```

Since [the official SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors) suggest that `vitePreprocess` [might be faster](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors-svelte-preprocess), I was wondering if I can set up global mixins with it.

I tried importing `prepend.scss` in my root `+layout.svelte` file but now I'm getting an `Undefined mixin` error.

Can I use mixins with `vitePreprocess` or is `svelte-preprocess` the only way to achieve this at the moment?

Comment: Hi, i also have the same issue, i still don't no how to use mixin and global files with sveltekit. I migrate my SPA from Svelte to SvelteKit, i also had to change the preprocess :(

Comment: It looks like at the moment, you can't. vitePreprocess does not support global styles. I had to revert to svelte-preprocess.

Answer (score 8):

As @SlavenIvanov's answer suggests, you have to import the **variables** and **mixins** from `vite.config.js`.

---

###### Here is a complete example of Sass configuration on a new SvelteKit project:

1. Create the [project](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project) (`npm create svelte@latest my-app`)
2. Add **vitePreprocess** in `svelte.config.js` (see [SvelteKit Preprocessors](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors-vitepreprocess))
3. Add **Sass** support with `npm install -D sass`
4. Import **variables** and **mixins** from `vite.config.js` (see [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions))
5. Import **global styles** from main layout (like described [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/faq.md#where-should-i-put-my-global-styles))

```js
// svelte.config.js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
 
export default {
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess()]
};
```

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
          @import '$lib/sass/variables'
          @import '$lib/sass/mixins'
        `,
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```scss
// src/lib/sass/_variables.sass
$red: #d34a
$green: #9c3
$blue: #0bc
```

```scss
// src/lib/sass/_mixins.sass
=tablet
  @media (min-width: 768px)
    @content

=desktop
  @media (min-width: 1024px)
    @content
```

```scss
// src/lib/sass/global.sass

html
  background: $red

  +tablet
    background: $blue
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+layout.svelte -->
<script>
  import '$lib/sass/global.sass'
</script>

<slot />
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<style lang="sass">
  h1
    color: $green

    +desktop
      color: $red
</style>
```

---

**Notes**:

1. I don't know why but you have to add an extra line break at the beginning of the `global.sass` file (otherwise it crashes)
2. You can disable WebStorm warnings such as `Element is resolved only by name...` by unchecking the box in Settings... "Editor / Inspections / Sass/SCSS / Missing import"

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your solution (with scss but I guess it's the same process) but I'm stuck. In your 4. the link you provide ask to make the import in a JS file and not in +layout.svelte. Is it supposed to be the same ?
Also, I don't understand how _mixins and _variables can be imported if you don't link them somewhere. Maybe the "_" prefix ? 
I'm starting my first sveltekit project and like you I Have been wandering around for a solution that you seem confident with. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 6):

Some good answers here, but there still seems to be some confusions in the answers, let me clear them up.

You need to update two files, `svelte.config.js` and `vite.config.js` to get this working.

#### Update svelte.config.js

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'; // Add this


const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()] // And this
};

export default config;
```

### Update vite.config.js

This is the confusing part, since this config will vary from person to person and what you are trying to do.

- You must be using either `.scss` or `.sass`, figure out which one you are using and don't mix them in the config.
- Figure out the path of your `.scss` or `.sass` files that you want to include throughout the project. In this case, it's `/src/lib/scss/`, for you it could be `/src/` or `/src/scss/`
- With this config vite will include all the sass/scss and if some of them are actual styles and not just variables, those styles will be duplicated in the final bundle. For the same reason, we will use `@use` and not `@import`.

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    // Add this
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            // if using SCSS
            scss: {                                 
                additionalData: `
                @use '$lib/scss/variables' as *;    
                @use '$lib/scss/mixins' as *;
            `,
            },
            // if using SASS
            sass: {                                 
                additionalData: `
                @use '$lib/sass/variables' as *;    
                @use '$lib/sass/mixins' as *;
            `,
            },
        },
    }
});
```

#### Usage

```scss
// src/lib/scss/_variables.scss

$color: red;
```

```scss
// src/lib/scss/_mixins.scss

@mixin big-font {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->

...

<style lang="scss">
    h2 {
        color: $color;
        @include big-font;
    }
</style>
```

**To explicitly use variables and mixins you can give them an alias**

```js
scss: {
    additionalData: `
    @use '$lib/scss/variables' as vr;   
    @use '$lib/scss/mixins' as mx;
    `,
},
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->

...

<style lang="scss">
    h2 {
        color: vr.$color;
        @include mx.big-font;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you mate! A simple solution that works flawlessly with the current version of SvelteKit (as of 16th Aug 23).
Cheers and take care o/

Comment: This seems to have a downside of confusing VS Code. The linter marks +page.svelte with an error because it can't see variables in those files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your prependData to `vite.config.ts` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68131954/how-to-use-sass-using-in-vuejs3-vite).

It should look like this:

```js
// vite.config.ts

const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
//  This is the magic 
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `@import './src/styles/prepend.scss';`
            }
        }
    }
}
```